# Orbital Mechanics: Initial velocity of a Parabolic trajectory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, solar-system

If I want to calculate the initial velocity, say for a planet orbiting a massive body, can I use the vis-viva equation in terms of eccentricity, and plug $e = 1$, to obtain the initial velocity that would create a parabolic motion?

$v = \sqrt{G \cdot M \cdot (\frac{2}{r}-\frac{1}{a})}$

and 
$a = \frac{\text{SemiMinor}}{\sqrt{1 - e^2}} $

.

Like wise, can I follow the same procedure with $e > 1$ for Hyperbolic trajectories?

Answer (score 1):

The vis-viva equation holds for parabolas and hyperbolas, so yes, you can use it to obtain an initial velocity if you also know $r$, the distance to that initial point.

However, you would not be able to directly use the equation for the semimajor axis, $a$, that you provided. Plugging in $e = 1$ or $e > 1$ to that equation does not really give a result at all. The $\sqrt{1-e^2}$ in the denominator equals zero for $e = 1$ and is undefined for $e > 1$. So for a parabola, $a = ∞$ (making the $1/a$ term in the vis-viva equation equal to zero). For a hyperbola, $a$ is negative.

As a bit of a side note: If you're just trying to determine the initial velocity for an object starting at infinity, $v = 0$ for parabolic orbits (since the total energy of such an object must be zero; this can also be verified using the vis-viva equation, plugging in $a = ∞$, $r = ∞$). For hyperbolic orbits with an object starting from infinity, the value of $v$ of course depends on the orbital parameters, but any initial velocity greater than zero will result in a hyperbolic orbit.

Comment: Thank you for responding. What formula would I be able to use to plug into the visa viva equation to determine the velocity of a Parabolic or Hyperbolic trajectory? Say I have a body 1 AU from the Sun, how could I calculate these parabolic/hyperbolic initial velocities using vis viva?

Comment: For a parabolic initial velocity, plug in ∞ for a (which means 1/a = 0) and 1 AU for r, which gives v = sqrt(2GM/1AU). For a hyperbolic initial velocity, if you're trying to calculate v for ANY hyperbola, any velocity greater than the parabolic v will give you that (because a parabola is the limiting case between hyperbola and ellipse - any lower velocity gives you an ellipse; any higher velocity gives you a hyperbola); if it's a specific hyperbolic orbit, you need to know the semimajor axis which you can get in a couple of ways, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola.

Comment: If I am calculating the initial velocity for elliptical orbits using the vis-viva equation do I start at Aphelion or Perihelion?

Comment: To answer that question you should just ask whether the object starts from aphelion or perihelion. It could also be a point in between. You can pick any point on the ellipse to start the object from, and the vis-viva equation will work the same way.